# Tutorials - Understanding ROS Nodes

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I have Ubuntu 10.04 and installes ROS electric.

I am trying to make $ rosmake turtlesim (Tutorials - Understanding ROS Nodes), but get following error message:

rosmake  Packages requested are: ['turtlesim']
rosmake  Logging to directory/home/janina/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120802-160904
rosmake  Expanded args ['turtlesim'] to:
[]
rosmake  WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['turtlesim']
rosmake  ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.

How can I install the turtlesim package? I think it,s missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40424/tutorials---understanding-ros-nodes/) by [Janina](https://answers.ros.org/users/1871/janina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to export the package paths correctly. As you allready noticed your packages can not be found. The reason is most likely that you did not correct setup the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH variable.

you can check the Path by:

## echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

The output shows the paths which ROS is searching for Packages.

Check also this page [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables)

---

Originally posted by [tlinder](https://answers.ros.org/users/2680/tlinder/) with karma: 663 on 2012-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorial assumes you have first completed the tutorial before:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages

That's where it explains how to get turtlesim.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Turtlesim comes as a stack by default with your ros-electric installation. However, if you believe its still missing you may [Click here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlesim) to obtain the package from the ROS website.

As said by tlinder you may have to check your $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH in order to see if ros is able to locate the package present in your folders. We may be able to help further if you can post the output of the following command:

echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [SivamPillai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2018/sivampillai/) with karma: 612 on 2012-08-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1